# AngularJs Web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, webservice-client

I want to get books name from this URL

```
http://localhost:3000/greeting
```

This is my nodejs Expressjs Server Code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/greeting', function (req, res) {

var books = {
    id : 555,
    name : 'Antony',
    title : 'Do or Die',
    price : {
        inr : 500,
        dollar : 5
        }
    };
    res.json(books);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

This code is my Angularjs webservice call named as `hello.js`

```
var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp', []);
app.controller('booksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/greeting")
   .then(function(response) {
  $scope.data = response.data;
  console.log("result"+response.data);
  });
});
```

This is My HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<article ng-app="booksInventoryApp">
    <section ng-controller="booksCtrl">
        <h2 ng-repeat="book in data.books">{{book.name}}</h2>    
    </section>
</article>




</body>
</html>
```

I want to GET Name of Book... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main `app` name is `booksInventoryApp` so you should include `ng-app="booksInventoryApp"` and also each page have one `ng-app` directive.

So try change

```
 ng-app="demo"
```

to

```
 ng-app="booksInventoryApp"
```

and remove  `ng-app="booksInventoryApp"` from `<article ng-app="booksInventoryApp">`

Answer (score 1):

What is the behaviour that you are seeing right now? Are there any errors?

The code looks okay to me. There can be multiple angular apps in a single page (if that is what you intend).

The problem I see is that the response is a JSON object and not an Array. So in the HTML, you have to simple change

```
<h2 ng-repeat="book in data.books">{{book.name}}</h2>
```

to

```
<h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
```

and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The reference to booksInventoryApp module in `<div ng-app="booksInventoryApp">` is from `angular.module('booksInventoryApp', [])`. So You gotta use `ng-app="booksInventoryApp"` instead of  `ng-app="demo"`, and remove `ng-app` from article tag

"The name of your module is whatever you give to it as your first argument, in this case `'booksInventoryApp'`. Putting ng-app in the html let's angular know what module you want to use as the main application module. The way it knows which one you want is by matching up the names, otherwise it won't be able to find it."

More explanation here [ng-app](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/angularjs/angularjs-ng-app-directive)